# PHP: Is it safe to use any value for the filename of a download?

Tags: php, download, websecurity

For example, with the following code to output a file to the user

`header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"');`

Is it safe to use any value there? The file is stored with an alphanumeric ID, but ideally it'd like to serve the download with the same filename it was uploaded with. However, I'm hesitant to allow this as I'm not sure what the implications could be.

Comment: You can clean filenames to ensure they haven't got any char that could generate a problem.

Comment: That filename is just a suggestion to the browser. The user will still have to respond to a save-file dialogue, and they can edit the filename. I believe the directory should be ignored by the browser, so you can't use it to save a file into an inappropriate folder.

Comment: I think this is actually a really good security question, although I don’t know if this is the right place for it. As Barnar noted, it is intended as a suggestion, however I can’t say for certain it is universally implemented. I know wget and curl ignore it unless you manually use it. But I honestly can’t say without testing that the major browsers implement it this way in a secure fashion

Comment: Thanks. I did rename a file to obscure (single quotes, double quotes, forward and backslashes and Windows (and Chrome) did replace certain characters like slashes and the double quotes to underscores but I'm not sure if that's a Windows thing or a Chrome thing. I can try asking on security.stackexchange.com I guess

Comment: The specification already has suggestions on what clients _should_ do, https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc6266.html#disposition.parameter.filename - but there is no guarantee all will. But you can probably take that as a rough guide on what you might want to already filter out on the server side.

Comment: @CBroe thank you I'll read through that